# How can I fix this memory leak in my SharePoint Powershell script?

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, memory-leaks

Purpose of the script: due to our Active Directory infrastructure, we add about 6000 entries directly to the Site User Info List so that they are shown in the address book in the SharePoint people picker.
The script creates about 6000 SPUser objects in order to add them to the Site User Info List. Most of them already exist, in this case new-SPUser should do nothing, right?

EDIT: please leave a feedback or possible solution. I removed some of the large log for better overview and added some details. Perhaps you know another forum where I should post this question?

I get lots of messages like this:

> Potentially excessive number of SPRequest objects (20) currently
>   unreleased on thread 9.  Ensure that this object or its parent (such
>   as an SPWeb or SPSite) is being properly disposed. This object is
>   holding on to a separate native heap.This object will not be
>   automatically disposed. Allocation Id for this object: {...snip...} Stack
>   trace of current allocation: at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.CreateSPRequestAndSetIdentity(SPSite
>   site, String name, Boolean bNotGlobalAdminCode, String strUrl, Boolean
>   bNotAddToContext, Byte[] UserToken, String userName, Boolean
>   bIgnoreTokenTimeout, Boolean bAsAnonymous)
>   ...snip...

And lots of messages like this:

> 08/17/2011 19:38:35.26    PowerShell.exe (0x1388)     0x20C0  SharePoint Foundation   Performance     nask    Monitorable An SPRequest object was reclaimed by the garbage collector instead of being explicitly freed.  To avoid wasting system resources, dispose of this object or its parent (such as an SPSite or SPWeb) as soon as you are done using it.  Allocation Id: {09C61E87-2BA1-4CEA-BB3C-266A1345559A}  To determine where this object was allocated, set Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService.ContentService.CollectSPRequestAllocationCallStacks = true.    de663eab-8063-4381-88b5-01cc50d51b77

This is the current script with highlighted four lines (`# ***`) that we added to solve it (did not work).

```
Write-Host "Fill Site User Info List for "$args[0]
add-pssnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Start-SPAssignment -Global    # ***

#global properties
$ppFilter = "(...)"

get-date

$ldapFilter = "(...)"
$ldapDirectory = "LDAP://DC=..."
Write-Host "Get all users from ..."
$de = New-Object system.directoryservices.directoryentry($ldapDirectory)
$de
$newsearch = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($de)
write-host "Filter all active users with ..."
$newsearch.Filter = $ldapFilter
$newsearch.PageSize = 200
$result = $newsearch.FindAll()

write-Host "Get all domain user accounts..."
$useraccounts = $result | % {"..."}

$siteCollection = get-spsite $args[0]
$webApp = $siteCollection.WebApplication

Write-Host "clear people picker filter" $webApp.Name "..."
$webApp.peoplepickersettings.ActiveDirectoryCustomFilter = ""
$webApp.Update()

write-Host "---------------"
$siteUrl = $siteCollection.Url
Write-Host "add "$useraccounts.Count" users to site collection "$siteUrl "..."
$start =  get-date
$site = $siteCollection.RootWeb       # ***
foreach ($user in $useraccounts) { 
    $current = New-SPUser -UserAlias $user -Web $site   # *** was before: $siteUrl
}
$end = get-date
$end - $start
$SiteCollection.Dispose()
Write-Host "---------------"

Write-Host "set people picker filter to" $ppFilter "..."
$webApp.peoplepickersettings.ActiveDirectoryCustomFilter = $ppFilter
$webApp.Update()

Stop-SPAssignment -Global    # ***

Write-Host "Done."
get-date
```

Is there an obvious error we made? Thank you for any suggestions.

In answer to @x0n I post a larger portion of the log. Sorry for this unreadable formatting. Is there a better way to post logs? All line breaks and tab spaces are messed up.

The point is, that the messages about reclaimed SPRequest object come from the powershell process. I am perfectly sure that this script was the only one running. This script used to finish within less than 10 Minutes, but now it does not finish even after 1.5 hours. I am pretty sure I did not change anything in the script that changed the behaviour. The performance view of the Windows Task Manager did show a moderate load on CPU and quite high usage of RAM (not all the way to 100%) while the script was running.

> Timestamp                  Process                     TID     Area                    Category        EventID Level       Message     Correlation
>   08/17/2011 19:38:34.30     PowerShell.exe (0x1388)     0x20C0  SharePoint Foundation   PowerShell      6tf0    Medium      Entering EndProcessing Method of New-SPUser.
>   08/17/2011 19:38:34.30     PowerShell.exe (0x1388)     0x20C0  SharePoint Foundation   PowerShell      6tf0    Medium      Leaving EndProcessing Method of New-SPUser.
>   08/17/2011 19:38:34.30     PowerShell.exe (0x1388)     0x20C0  SharePoint Foundation   PowerShell      6tf0    Medium      Entering BeginProcessing Method of New-SPUser.  de663eab-8063-4381-88b5-01cc50d51b77
>   08/17/2011 19:38:34.30     PowerShell.exe (0x1388)     0x20C0  SharePoint Foundation   PowerShell      6tf0    Medium      Leaving BeginProcessing Method of New-SPUser.   de663eab-8063-4381-88b5-01cc50d51b77
>   08/17/2011 19:38:34.30     PowerShell.exe (0x1388)     0x20C0  SharePoint Foundation   PowerShell      6tf0    Medium      Entering ProcessRecord Method of New-SPUser.    de663eab-8063-4381-88b5-01cc50d51b77
>   08/17/2011 19:38:34.30     PowerShell.exe (0x1388)     0x20C0  SharePoint Foundation   Performance     naqx    Monitorable Potentially excessive number of SPRequest objects (19) currently unreleased on thread 9.  Ensure that this object or its parent (such as an SPWeb or SPSite) is being properly disposed. This object is holding on to a separate native heap.This object will not be automatically disposed. Allocation Id for this object: {815F9A3D-6635-42FA-9658-B6294968136E} Stack trace of current allocation:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.CreateSPRequestAndSetIdentity(SPSite site, String name, Boolean bNotGlobalAdminCode, String strUrl, Boolean bNotAddToContext, Byte[] UserToken, String userName, Boolean bIgnoreTokenTimeout, Boolean bAsAnonymous)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRequestManager.GetContextRequest(SPRequestAuthenticationMode authenticationMode)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.g... de663eab-8063-4381-88b5-01cc50d51b77
>
> ( .... snip ....)
>
> 08/17/2011 19:38:34.30     PowerShell.exe (0x1388)     0x20C0  SharePoint Foundation   Performance     naqx    Monitorable Potentially excessive number of SPRequest objects (19) currently unreleased on thread 9.  Ensure that this object or its parent (such as an SPWeb or SPSite) is being properly disposed. This object is holding on to a separate native heap. Allocation Id for this object: {F9CDF3DA-41B1-485D-B78F-0266545C417A} Stack trace of current allocation:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.CreateSPRequestAndSetIdentity(SPSite site, String name, Boolean bNotGlobalAdminCode, String strUrl, Boolean bNotAddToContext, Byte[] UserToken, String userName, Boolean bIgnoreTokenTimeout, Boolean bAsAnonymous)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitializeSPRequest()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitWebPublic()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_Exists()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPWebPipeBind.Rea... de663eab-8063-4381-88b5-01cc50d51b77
>
> (... snip ...)
>   (... many of those messages: )
>   08/17/2011 19:38:35.26     PowerShell.exe (0x1388)     0x20C0  SharePoint Foundation   Performance     nask    Monitorable An SPRequest object was reclaimed by the garbage collector instead of being explicitly freed.  To avoid wasting system resources, dispose of this object or its parent (such as an SPSite or SPWeb) as soon as you are done using it.  Allocation Id: {09C61E87-2BA1-4CEA-BB3C-266A1345559A}  To determine where this object was allocated, set Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService.ContentService.CollectSPRequestAllocationCallStacks = true.    de663eab-8063-4381-88b5-01cc50d51b77

Answer (score 4):

This message does not actually indicate a leak - the key thing here is the word "potentially." All that message means is that your thread has a lot open at the same time. The threshhold for emitting that message is actually set quite low for practical use. What's really important is that they are disposed correctly at the end of their lifetime. If you *really* had a leak, you'd see messages like this:

> 05/012/2011 12:58:47.31                w3wp.exe (0x105C)
>   0x09A8 Windows SharePoint Services                   General
>   8l1n       High       **An SPRequest object was not disposed before the
>   end of this thread.**  To avoid wasting system resources, dispose of
>   this object or its parent (such as an SPSite or SPWeb) as soon as you
>   are done using it.  This object will now be disposed.  Allocation Id:
>   {5BFFCA4B-3B91-45BF-98CD-0BB508BE30EE} To determine where this object
>   was allocated, create a registry key at
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server
>   Extensions\HeapSettings. Then create a new DWORD named
>   SPRequestStackTrace with the value 1 under this key.

Stefan Grossner has a great article explaining the reasoning behind all of this, including why the threshold for the warning is probably too low (and how you can change it to something more practical.)

http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2008/05/07/troubleshooting-spsite-spweb-leaks-in-wss-v3-and-moss-2007.aspx

Incidentally, even if you did have a leak and you couldn't find it, closing the powershell process will return the memory.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. There are lots of messages like you pointed out. I will add them to the original post so everybody sees them. I can not see, that many site or web objects are created in the script, only lots of SPUser objects, which are not disposable.

Comment: After reviewing the text and the script I think this does not help, because in the script I handle only one site and one web object. Perhaps the New-SPUser causes new open SPRequest objects?

Comment: Are you sure it's even coming from your script? What's the associated process in the log? If it's w3wp.exe then it's not powershell. You should see powershell.exe as the process generating the errors.

Comment: Yes I am sure. I added the log to the original post. Here is the description from above: The messages about reclaimed SPRequest object come from the powershell process. I am perfectly sure that this script was the only one running. This script used to finish within less than 10 Minutes, but now it does not finish even after 1.5 hours. The performance view of the Windows Task Manager did show a moderate load on CPU and quite high usage of RAM (not all the way to 100%) while the script was running. I am pretty sure I did not change anything in the script that changed the behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

`System.DirectoryServices` also uses unmanaged objects.

You will need to dispose of your directoryentry and directorysearcher objects, and I think also the searchresultcollection object that is implicitly created by powershell on your behalf.

Answer (score 0):

You should dispose SP objects, especially SPWeb and SPSite carefully.

Best practices reference:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rogerla/archive/2008/02/12/sharepoint-2007-and-wss-3-0-dispose-patterns-by-example.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248.aspx

Issue Reference Blog:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2008/05/07/troubleshooting-spsite-spweb-leaks-in-wss-v3-and-moss-2007.aspx

VS plugin to detect Sharepoint Leaks:
https://spdisposecheck2012.codeplex.com/